# Is it possible to preserve DbContext while its saving data after the API returns response to web client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP .Net Core 3.1. I have a Web API built which generates a large amount of random data and saves it to the database using EF core. This takes a while to save.

I'd like to have the response returned to the client while the context continues to save.

I've tried using DBContext.SaveChangesAsync without having the calling method wait/await (so execution continues and the API method returns OK to the calling Web UI), it seems as though the save stops executing the save once the WebAPI method returns.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Generate the data, return it to the client. Before you return it, use a `Task` to do the saving. You may need to new up a lifetime scope (or the equivalent in your IoC container) to make sure the context doesn't get closed at the end of the web request.

Comment: Of course, there will be a risk that you have returned data to the client that doesn't successfully save  (e.g. the DB is down).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the Task. But I'm not sure how to "new up a lifetime scope" @mjwills

Comment: What IoC container are you using? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html

Comment: Ended up using the Task to run the code I needed but also injected an instance of IServiceScopeFactory which I then used to create a new scope and context, which I then used to save the data. This seemed to work

Comment: Awesome - great work!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Background Thread` and `IServiceScopeFactory`. I have done similar thing for one of my project here is the sample code

```
public static void StartRandomDataThread(this IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    Thread worker = new Thread(async () => await SaveRandomData(serviceScopeFactory))
    {
        IsBackground = true
    };
    worker.Start();
}

private static async Task SaveRandomData(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        //Or you can pass list of data as parameter while starting the thread
        var someRandomData = ....;
        
        foreach (var data in someRandomData)
        {
            dbContext.Add(data);        
        }
        
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    };
}
```

And then you can call this from your controller or service

```
_serviceScopeFactory.StartRandomDataThread();
//continue the execution
```

you wil get `_serviceScopeFactory` from constructor injection of dependency